# Meaning of "Auf, zu, auf, zu, auf zu ..."

Tags: meaning, phrase

At the Munich airport last week, I saw a sign that said:

> Auf, zu, auf, zu, auf zu Sixt.

(Sixt is a car-rental company.)  I have not been able to find any translation of this expression to English.  One German-speaking friend said it means something like:

> Wow, off we go to Sixt, isn’t that great?

but she admitted that she could not translate it into English easily.

Is there a better translation, and what are the conditions in which it can be used?  It sounds like something only children would say about going to an amusement park.  Can adults use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a play on words. On the one hand, we're looking at a convertible. The two states can be called "auf" and "zu", and the ad suggests that converting a convertible over and over is lots of fun, so you should rent one from Sixt. 
In order to do that you have to go to Sixt, and that is the second meaning.

> Auf zu XYZ.

This is an exclamation meaning

> Let's go to XYZ.

The "zu" is a regular local preposition and the "auf" might be borrowed from/inspired by "aufbrechen" which is a the high register brother of "losgehen"... to head out, to start the journey.

EDIT:

Thanks to @Dan Leifker for the [link with the image](http://www.leifker.com/perm/misc/aufzu.png)

Comment: I think, also this punctuation would be fine, even if it was not used on the sign.

Comment: Here it is: [link](http://www.leifker.com/perm/misc/aufzu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Saying "Auf zu Sixt." would be normal German meaning like in your proposal "Let's go to Sixt" like in "Auf nach Italien." (Let's go to Italy).
Repeating this for three times is not common for such a phrase in German but here it is used as a stylistic device for advertising.

Comment: You totally fail to mention the joke here, which is the difference between "auf, zu" (open, close) and "auf zu" (let's go to).